# How do I send data only by WiFi

Tags: android, android-wifi

In my downloader I have to let the user choose whether he wants to download by WiFi or by using network connectivity. I know I can do this via:

```
final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
 this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

final android.net.NetworkInfo wifi =
 connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
```

and then use the `isConnected()` method to see if I have WiFi connectivity. I also have another class named `Sharable`, not an `Activity`, which is supposed to hold all the data that is to be shared across Activities. These 'sharable' things include connections to database and so on.

How can I get this WiFi information in this `Sharable` class ?
Can this not be achieved without it extending `Activity` ?
If not, where am I supposed to instantiate the various variables ? In the `onCreate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass Application context to `Sharable`.